# JSON.parse Error after decoding JSON.stringify-ed Array

Tags: php, json, form-data

I want to submit an array of arrays through JSON. So I create an object, apply JSON.stringify() on it and set it to a formData...

```
    var sources = new Array();
    $('.source-instance').each(function(){

        var auxObject = {};
        auxObject["sourceTitle"] = $(this).find(".source-title").val();   

        sources.push(auxObject);
        console.log('sources: ' + JSON.stringify(sources));
    });

    formData.set('sources', JSON.stringify(sources));
```

When I check the data

```
console.log(formData.get('sources'))
```

I get

```
[{"sourceTitle":"SomeTitle"},{"sourceTitle":"AnotherTitle"}]
```

... which I then proceed via AJAX to the server.

On server side in php I loop over the array and let it print:

```
foreach (json_decode($request['sources'], true) as $sourceInstance) {
    print_r($sourceInstance);
}
```

I get

```
Array
(
    [sourceTitle] => SomeTitle
)
Array
(
    [sourceTitle] => AnotherTitle
)
```

which looks pretty fine. But I also get

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

How come that? And how can I repair this? I don't see, where it is coming from.

**EDIT**
the ajax looks like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/piece/store',
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: 'JSON',     
        data: formData,
        success: function(response){
           if (response.status == 'error'){
              // show the erors
           }
           if (response.status == 'success'){ // "redirect" to success page
               window.location.replace('/succes');
           }
        },
        error: function(response){
           $(".optional.errors").show();
           $('ul.errors').empty();
           $.each(response.errors, function (index, error) {
               $('ul.errors').append('<li>' + error + '</li>');
           });    
       }
    });
```

the php responds:

```
$response = [
    'status' => 'success',
];                     
return response()->json($response);
```

Comment: That error message doesn't come from the code you got in the question. Show us your ajax call and how you handle the response. It's probably when you're trying to parse the response (in the ajax callback) it fails, since your code doesn't return json (you have print_r() in your php-code).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson That's it. When I delete the print_r() everything is fine. But I wonder how it does affect the response?

Comment: I added an answer with an explanation. Feel free to accept it if it helped you with your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message happens when jQuery is trying to parse the response from the ajax call.

In your ajax request, you have set: `dataType: 'json'`, which tells jQuery to expect the response to be a json-string. jQuery will then try to parse that json-string into a json-object (using JSON.parse()).

However, since you have `print_r($sourceInstance)` in your PHP-code, the response won't be a valid json-string and will make `JSON.parse()` fail.

*Any* output on the server side (echo, var_dump, print_r etc) will be a part of the response.